# VWKWebView and Access-Control-Allow-Origin Issue

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, wkwebview

Just created Cordova 6.0 project to test out the JS performance of VWKWebView. Unfortunately, I've been stuck because I need to fetch some JSON from a remote server, and I have run into CORS related issue.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8085/spring/login/mobile/service?version=4.0.1. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I have "cordova-plugin-whitelist" plugin installed, and my config.xml already has:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

After some Googling, I found a related issue on Apache's bug tracker - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10359. Comments suggests that 'cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine' is responsible for this issue, and I guess it's a limitation introduced by Apple, and not the plugin maintainer himself.

Has anybody figured a workaround or is it impossible to use VWKWebView on production worthy hybrid apps?

Comment: [Google Group of Cordova/Phonegap](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/phonegap)

Comment: Read the README.md However, you are still not able to use XHR from the file:// protocol without CORS enabled on your server. So you have to enable CORS on your server or use the wkwebview-engine-localhost https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins/tree/master/wkwebview-engine-localhost

Comment: @jcesarmobile CORS have been enabled, I can verify because the same web service works fine with UIWebView. When I run curl, I see CORS headers in the response.

Comment: Do you use authentication headers? that doesn't seem to work on WKWebView

Comment: @jcesarmobile No, I don't use authetication headers, but my response has `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, and it's working on other Cordova apps.

Comment: You are using a simulator to test, right? because you are using localhost and a real device won't connect to localhost. Can you share the code you are using? Can you connect to this url? `http://www.jcesar.16mb.com/allowAll.php`

Comment: @jcesarmobile When I try to call that URL, I get the same error message.I'm using iOS simulator to test, it must be just as capable as a real device. It can access localhost. Maybe OS X does smart port forwarding to iOS Sim

Comment: I said localhost will only work on a simulator, not on a real device. If you can't connect to the url I provided, then the problem must be on your code, because I can connect to that url using WKWebView. Provide your code.